# JVM garbage collection - tracing live objects in young generation

Tags: java, performance, garbage-collection, jvm

While collecting the young generation memory, JVM collectors scan only those root objects (obejcts in the heap directly accessible from the root set) that belong to the young generation and also use a write barrier backed card table/remembered set to determine regions of the old generation which could possibly contain objects that contain references to objects in the young generation.

The question that I have is that if the young collector determines that a particular object in the young generation only has a single external reference from an object in the old generation, **how does it know if the old generation object itself is not garbage and thus making the young generation object 'live' and not eligible for collection?** For example, there could be a path from the root set directly to this object in the old generation that in turn has a reference to the said young generation object. **Does the young collector typically consider this young generation object as live or does it some how determine whether the old generation object pointing to it is live/garbage before deciding to ignore/collect it?**

Answer (score 6):

> how does it know if the old generation object itself is not garbage?

It doesn't that is what a major/full collection is for. The assumption is that old gen object doesn't die often.

When a full collection is performed it checks all the objects, but when a minor/young collection is performed only the objects in the young collection are cleaned up.

Comment: Thanks for your reply - I was less concerned about the collection of the old generation object but the survival/collection of the young generation object during a young GC. So if I understand correctly from what you said, if we have a young generation object that only has an incoming reference from an old generation object which itself is garbage, this young generation object (which is garbage) survives young GCs and is collected only in the first young GC that happens after a major GC that collects the said old generation object.

Comment: Basically yes. I think actually the "Full" generation involves a collection of both the young and old spaces at the same time, because "why not" and also because you also need to mark from roots and through objects in the young generation to find all the reachable old generation objects. So you could simply it to "those objects won't be collected until the next full gc". @Stormshadow

Answer (score 1):

The question is “how to you get to such a scenario?”

To create a reference from an old object to a young object, the old object must be reachable, as otherwise we can’t store a reference to the young object in it. In order to become unreachable afterwards, we have to modify at least either, a root reference or another old object that previously referenced the old object in question.

As you already mentioned, these kind of writes are tracked by the JVM, which is crucial, as in order to detect that an old object now references a young object, it must know that the memory area of the old object (aka card) has been modified. In principle, since card marking also implies remembering the incoming references, the gc is now capable of detecting that the old object became unreachable, even without a major gc. It only has to consider the modified card (or the root set) to learn about it. Whether it does, depends on environmental factors, like the chosen gc algorithm, i.e. whether you use CMS (won’t) or G1 (might), and how “mixed collections” are configured or the actual memory pressure.

Of course, if you use a concurrent collector, there is the possibility that the modification that will make the old object unreachable happens while a collection cycle is already ongoing. In this situation, it is possible that the young object is considered reachable during this gc cycle, even if it wasn’t if the modification happened just a nanosecond earlier.

Comment: I'm not following how that could work. While it is true that writes that make an old-gen object not-reachable will be captured by the card mark, the young collection can't really use that information to prove that any particular old gen object is unreachable: to do that it would need to do a full mark of the whole old gen, to understand the actual final effect of _all_ the writes to the old gen since the last collection. Essentially it would have to do a full gc.

Comment: Think of the card-marking as a conservative heuristic: it is capable of _conservatively_ increasing the increasing the reachable set when it notices a reference to a young object has been written into the old gen. This isn't always right - because it can't be sure the old gen object is still even reachable, but at least it is correct since a too-big reachable set is OK. On the other hand, it can't safely decrease the reachable set, since that change would have to be exact and just knowing a reference changed doesn't help you there.

Comment: @BeeOnRope: of course, this requires a *mixed collection*, incorporating the changed cards. Since in the OP’s hypothetical scenario there is only a sole root reference to the old object and the incoming references *are* remembered for a region, it is possible to detect that this single region-spanning reference is gone. Therefore, only the region has to be traversed to find out that there are no intra-region references left. I’m not saying that a young collection was sufficient, I’m only saying that you don’t need a full gc.

Comment: How can you _incorporate_ the changed cards other than a full collection of the entire region? A single write to any object within a region potentially changes the reachability of every object int he region in a complex way for the whole region. The "remembered set" of intra-region references is very simple: it just says "this object in region A is referenced by this object in region B" (A = young and B = old for the OP's example). It doesn't give you _any_ information you would need to determine how changing a reference can _shrink_ the remembered set. It only does a good job at growing it.

Comment: Of course, we might just be talking about different things. Speaking of "mixed collection" makes me think of G1. So perhaps your answer should be taken in the context of that collector? In that case, we violently agree: a "mixed collection" of both regions (the region with the incoming reference, here a young region) and the region that had the outgoing reference and had a dirty card: in the context of the traditional non-G1 collectors this is simply a "full collection" as Peter mentions. For G1, it might only collect 2 regions out of many, so very different...

Comment: @BeeOnRope: yes, I tend to think of G1 first, when I read “card marking”, though I tried to be as general as possible, only saying that it’s possible, not that it always happens. I inserted an explicit reference to the gc algorithm to mentioned “environmental factors”.